# Do the logs such as messages and syslog begin during or after installation?

Tags: boot, system-installation, log, syslog

I would like to know if logs such as `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages` begin their first loggings during the installation of the OS, or once the OS has already been installed and at the first normal boot?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is yes (although see my notes towards the bottom of the answer after the quotation from the manpage), but I have no recent installations to confirm this.

If you are trying to debug an installation, in addition to the `syslog` and `messages` logs, `ubiquity` (the liveCD installer) will also also send logging output to these files:

- `/var/log/installer/debug` (debugging output)
- `/var/log/installer/dm` (stands for display manager I believe, similar to `Xorg.0.log`)
- `/var/log/installer/version` (the version of `ubiquity`)
- `/var/log/partman` (logging from the partition manager)

These files will not be overwritten by more recent logging (as `syslog` and `messages` would), so they might be more useful in looking for installation errors.

If you require further detail you can also pass `-d` to `ubiquity` to enable verbose mode, as explained in the manpage:

```
     -d, --debug
       Run in debugging mode, sending verbose information to
       /var/log/installer/debug that may be useful to developers.  (The
       /var/log/syslog file is usually required in any case, along with
       /var/log/partman in the case of problems related to partitioning.)
       Note that passwords will be logged in debugging mode!
```

To to this, from a liveCD you can either press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run `ubiquity -d` (this might need root privileges, in which case add a `sudo`) or open a terminal and run the same command.  The messages about the `syslog` and `partman` files being required might indicate that they are not created until after installation, but in this case you should be able to make the files/directories first using `sudo mkdir` and `sudo nano`.

Another possibility would be that the logging would be done to the liveCD's virtual filesystem's `/var/log/syslog`, in which case you could open it and copy the information to a permanent destination being rebooting out of the live session and into the new installation.